# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP with UrlRewrite in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to be sure that whenever someone access a website from a secure connections (HTTPS) it is being redirected to HTTP.

Not sure how to do this. I've added this UrlRewrite Rule into my web.config, but it still gives an error: "The connection was reset".

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" /></conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Canonical rewrite">
         <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.redgold\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.redgold.com/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Daniel